# PHP: Form in loaded file using Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, post

I have to files, in one of them I call the other one using Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dataBox').load('/example/data.php?id=' + '123');
});
```

Then the data displays nicely in my div with the id "dataBox".
So far so good.

Though, in my data.php file for each data that is queried from the database there are a form. Simple form just a textfield and a submit button. This form sends the data using POST and then the first file grabs those values using `$_POST`. This doesn't work, before I moved the code that gets data to another file all worked fine. The form action parameter is set to `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`. I can with Google Chrome's developer inspecting thingy, see that it sends the values to data.php?id='123', which isn't that strange. So I thought that I would move all the code that picks up the POST values to the data.php file. Though that doesn't seem to work either. The page doesn't seem to refresh when I press submit.

EDIT:

I just noticed that I had written `<form ..some code .. /> instead of just <form ..some code .. >` That made the submit button "work" and it send the values. Though it sends me to the jQuery loaded page because of `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` as the action parameter. I need to make it so that it sends me to the page that loaded the file.

Comment: Could you post a snippet of your data.php?

Comment: Is `#dataBox` contained in another form by any chance? If so, you can't have nested forms.

Comment: @Jeff Just some data with a form sticked to each row. It worked when in the same file, look at the edit btw.

Comment: @bfavaretto Nope, just a simple div. :)

Comment: I think the reason for the incorrect redirection is the REQUEST_URI variable - try changing the action param to whatever it is your MAIN page is (the one where you load the data)

Comment: @Jeff I know that the REQUEST_URI is the problem but I need a dynamic variable and not just the main page. Or are there anyway to call a function  on the same page similar to $'#dataBox'.load(...)? That way I could have all code on the same page.

Comment: Sure, you can use jQuery - are you up for that? That means its all Async

Comment: Don't care as long it's safe and fast. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaaaand...SOLVED!

Just changed `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` to `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` thanks for all your help though! Made me understand what was wrong and more about how things work. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to reinitialize your jquery function when you load the new page.  Jquery doesn't know it exists unless you reinit like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dataBox').load('/example/data.php?id=' + '123', function(){
      reinit();
  });
});

function reinit() {
  $('#dataBox form').submit(function(){
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'myProcessingPage.php',
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
  });
}
```

Note:  This code is just to show you how it works, not meant for production.

Comment: AFAIK, he is not using jQuery to submit the form - see "**The form action parameter is set to $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]**", and that nothing happens when he presses submit. The submission should most likely work without any JS

Comment: Oh, well then I would also suggest using jQuery, if they're able to do so.

Comment: Yes, me too - but from the OP he wants the page to refresh.

Comment: @Jeff It doesn't have to refresh, just submit the POST data either to data.php or the original file that loads data.php. Then if that refreshes the page too, that is fine. :)

Comment: What I really need is to make the forms send me to the file that it is included in.

Comment: I updated the code with how to serialize a form and set it to a processing page.

Comment: @Oskwish:  Did my answer help you?  Could you accept it or give it an upvote?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery (1.7.2) solution (this is not complete, you have to modify for your needs, I am simply pointing out an alternate way of posting to your data.php without using the standard form submission):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Like you already have, load the form stuff on document ready
  $('#dataBox').load('/example/data.php?id=' + '123');
  // Now, let's hook a submit event up to your submit buttons - we'll attach it to dataBox so 
  // you wont have to bind it again:
  $("#dataBox").delegate("submit","FORM",function(e){
     // Prevent the form from submitting
     e.preventDefault();
     // Do the submission
     $.post("data.php",{id:"123"},function(result){
        // Now you can do whatever you want with result, as it
        // contains everything that data.php returned.
     });
  });
});
```